# Converting Expression<Func<TProperty>> to Func<TObject, TProperty> where TObject is known

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'm trying to convert an:

```
Expression<Func<TProperty>>
```

to a

```
Func<TObject, TProperty>
```

Where TObject is known and exposes the property expressed by the Expression. For this I imagine have to manipulate the Expression, combine it with the TObject type parameter in a new Expression, and compile.

Edit: Example input and output

```
class SomeType
{
   public int Number { get; set; }

   public Func<TObject, TProperty> FuncConverter<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>>)
   {
       // ???      
   }

   public void test()
   {
       Func<SomeType, int> outputFunc = FuncConverter<SomeType, int>(inputExpression);
   }
}
```

An expression I expect as input:

```
Expression<Func<int>> inputExpression = () => Number;
```

This expression points to the Number property on SomeType

A Func delegate that I expect as output:

```
Func<SomeType, int> outputFunc = type => type.Number;
```

End Edit

The problem is, I have no idea to how to do that. I would really appreciate some (references to) accessible information on manipulating Lambda expressions as I have not yet come across any.

Comment: ignoring the typo, I'm not sure I understand how a function that takes no parameters can be converted to a function that takes a parameter.

Comment: `Where TObject is known and exposes the property expressed by the Expression` -> this is the sentence I am having lots of troubles understanding. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Jodrell The Expression points to a property on the Object. I'm assuming that, combined with knowledge of the Object Type, it would be possible to construct a new Expression which I can use as an EqualityComparer in a Collection's ToDictionary method. Are you saying it is impossible?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Psier, sorry but I still have doubts and trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. Could you please provide an example expression that you will have as input and example expression that you expect as output? With some dummy sample types. It will make your question much more understandable.

Comment: `() => Number` won't compile unless `Number` is a property on the object *creating* that expression.

Comment: How complex can the input expression be. What if the input expression is: `() => 123;` What do you expect as output expression in this case? `Func<SomeType, int> outputFunc = type => type.123;` hardly makes any sense. There must be some relation between the input expression and the `TObject` that you are trying to use as output, otherwise your problem is undefined and cannot be solved in the general case.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The input Expression would always point to a Property on the object creating that expression. Its specific use is to point to a property. As far as I can tell, one cannot have a property with '123' as its name.

Comment: But if the input expression is already pointing to a property on the `TObject` type, you already know `TObject`, don't you? What's the point of specifying it once again for the output expression?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I need the output Func for another purpose, namely as an EqualityComparer in a ToDictionary method. Obviously my example is greatly simplified in an attempt to keep focus on the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Well then I guess a more realistic example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question:

```
Func<TObject, TProp> Converter<TObject, TProp>(Expression<Func<TProp>> propertyExpression )
    {
        MemberExpression member = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

        // Get the Property information of the propertyExpression memberExpression
        var property = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        // Get the Declaring type information from member expression (equivalent to TObject)
        var type = member.Member.DeclaringType;

        // Define the source Parameter for the new Func delegate
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "source");
        var source = Expression.Convert(param, type);

        // Get the property on the source
        var get = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(source, property);
        var convert = Expression.Convert(get, typeof(TProp));

        // Construct the Expression
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TObject, TProp>>(convert, param);

        // Compile to get the Func delegate type
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```

I found the information here: [link](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Lambda_and_Expression_Trees.aspx)

Slightly adapted it to solve my problem. Thanks to all commenters...